# Paste WMF image in VSTO Add-in for Word (Selecting current document)

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto, add-in, paste

I'm creating a VSTO Word Add-in in vb.net to paste images as windows metafiles (not enhanced metafiles as is the default in Word 2010). I have accomplished this before in VBA with the code:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial datatype:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
```

I'm looking for resources and help on

1. Obtaining the location of the cursor in the Word document (selection)
2. Check to see if the image is of a particular type (in this case WMF)
3. Paste an image to the document at the selection

Any help / links you can provide will be appreciated!

---EDIT---

I've been able to successfully paste a windows metafile image, but I'm unsure on how to select the current document. I can create a new word application object with a new document and then paste the image in there but I can't seem to select the already opened word instance. See code below (Note that I've tried oWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application") with no success)

```
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objDataTypeMetafile As New Object
    objDataTypeMetafile = Word.WdPasteDataType.wdPasteMetafilePicture

    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add

    oWord.Selection.PasteSpecial(, , , , objDataTypeMetafile, , )
    oWord = Nothing
    oDoc = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring oWord as Glocals.ThisAddIn.Application was the trick. Works perfectly now.

```
    Dim oWord As Word.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    Dim objDataTypeMetafile As New Object
    objDataTypeMetafile = Word.WdPasteDataType.wdPasteMetafilePicture

    oWord.Visible = True
    oWord.Selection.PasteSpecial(, , , , objDataTypeMetafile, , )
    oWord = Nothing
```